# Windows explorer.exe /select <filepath> doesn't work with new folders

Tags: windows, command-line, explorer

I copy or rename a folder containing some files.

Then, in a command line window I type:

`explorer /select,"<full-path-to-a-file-in-new-folder>"`

The result is, the folder opens but the file isn't selected.
Subsequent calls are fine, this happens only for newly created/renamed folders for the first time ever.

Is this a Windows bug? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Can you post some code that reproduces the issue even if it is just a batch file...

Comment: @Anders it is not a programming question. The "code" is what I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem while trying to use the `ShellExecuteEx()` to run the Explorer.exe with the /select, to pick a file.  Explorer doesn't reliably select the file the first time.  Maybe it's a bug ... I found a few work arounds for it.

- Set Explorer to execute as a separate process.  This can be done in folder options and selecting "Launch each folder windows in a separate process".
- Another workaround I found to work is creating a batch file to and launch Explorer from there with `explorer.exe /select,"%~1"` using the full file name as parameter into the batch file.
- The last solution is what I ended up doing since I'm writing a program in C++. I used `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()` function.

Comment: does your C++ solution overcome the exact scenario described in the question? If so, I'll accept the answer without having tried it myself.

Comment: I don't use the command line to execute my program.  And in the C++ solution, the Explorer /select function is not used.  I did tried to create a new folder and use my program, and it worked fine in selecting files.